# Does the detail in a manga affect the mangaka's payment?

Tags: manga-production

The series like ***Vagabond***, ***Vinland Saga***, ***Ichigo Mashimaro***, ***Made in Abyss***, ***Planetes***, ***I am Hero***, ***Gantz***, ***Inuyashiki***, and ***Yotsubato***  have such a surrealist and detailed background style. Did they get paid more than a regular one? Or the wages for every chapter they made are same with the other mangaka?

"These" mangaka have put a lot of effort for like adding detail to the background and such, the character, the environment, and so. I know other manga had some detail for their own style like *Akame ga Kill*, *Toriko*, *One Piece*, *Yu-Gi-Oh!* (in this context, the monster illustration in all of *Yu-Gi-Oh!* cards).

Compare it with "other mangaka", I thought they should get paid more but, but did they?

Answer (score 2):

Found something on search, I will try to make an answer out of it.

https://okuha.com/how-much-does-a-mangaka-earn/

> It’s actually not as common for a mangaka to be salaried, whether by
> an animation company or a publisher. Manga is sold like books; **how
> much a mangaka earns is usually dependent on the contract they’re
> offered.**
>
> [...]
>
> That begs the question, what happens if the artist’s manga goes viral
> and sells millions of copies? It’s not unheard of. Some mangas have
> massive followings and seemingly exploded overnight.
>
> Most manga authors receive a royalty from the sale of each volume, and
> if a manga gets especially popular, **the publisher is likely to
> extend the contract for further volumes (and at a higher rate).**
>
> This is a tricky field for mangakas to navigate. While sudden success
> may seem like a great thing, it also comes with a number of legal
> loopholes and red tape to clear.
>
> [...]
>
> In particular, manga artists have to really advocate for themselves in
> order to get the earnings that they deserve, especially when the manga
> gets its own anime.
>
> Some manga artists have remarked that allowed merchandise to be
> produced of their characters in exchange for a licensing fee (which is
> standard). But no royalties were ever negotiated.
>
> Therefore, companies make hundreds of thousands of dollars from the
> artists’ idea, while the artist only walks away with a **much smaller
> sum paid upfront.** [...] **Contracts are difficult to navigate**, and
> sometimes it’s best to get the advice of a lawyer before making any
> major decisions.

From the way it's seems, it's all depends on the contract, so as to the question "does good art makes it better" seems kinda far, since we see less good drawn manga that's getting much more money only on being popular. **The artist might claim to his publisher that his art is very high and all, but in the end it's depends on the publisher to agree**, the artist needs the publisher more than the publisher needs him, being mangaka is a gamble - in the end it's the popular ones who gets more money on selling volumes than increasing art quality.

[My most claim is that it isn't mentioned in that article anything related about the art, at the end of things he says that even the popular ones doesn't get much, it's hard to say that a better drawn manga will bring his author more money, manga business is all about popularity after all. But the author *might* demands to get paid more because of that, but in the end it's all end up on the publisher decides, and in most cases it'll be - lets see if this manga will work out if any.]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact there is sheer increase in number of manga in Japan being a manga artist is one of the professions one could choose over there.

Based on an article which I went through [online.](https://medium.com/@jasonmuell/ink-sweat-and-tears-how-much-does-a-manga-artist-earn-c98e1d311e3e#:%7E:text=A%20manga%20artist%20is%20generally,is%20around%2020%20pages%20each.) I saw that based on the manuscripts an artist is getting paid.

And not only this there are certain articles where it mentions about the dark theme behind every worker in this [link.](https://www.vox.com/culture/2019/7/2/20677237/anime-industry-japan-artists-pay-labor-abuse-neon-genesis-evangelion-netflix)

An animator named adachi mentioned that

> “Even if you move up the ladder and become a key-frame animator, you
> won’t earn much,” Adachi said. “And even if your title is a huge hit,
> like Attack on Titan, you won’t make any of it. … It’s a structural
> problem in the anime industry. There’s no dream [job as an animator].”

So by conclusion I could say they don't get much but they mostly get around a meager salary even if they are a top animator the pay scale is also mention in the site which is mentioned below:

> According to the Japanese Animation Creators Association,
> An animator in Japan earns on average ¥1.1 million (~$10,000) per year in their 20s
> ¥2.1 million (~$19,000) in their 30s
> And a livable but still meager ¥3.5 million (~$31,000) in their 40s and 50s. The poverty >line is Japan is ¥2.2 million.

Answer (score -4):

I think a mangaka gets paid according to how popular his/her manga is, but new manga artist get paid +- $100 per page. They don't care if it's more detailed or not, they only care about how popular the manga is.

Read the manga *Bakuman*, it will answer all your questions on manga.

Comment: Can you explain more about your answer ?

Comment: Could you provide references for this? If this is explained in *Bakuman*, could you provide the volume/chapter no.?

Comment: Need more explanation and a link to support that explanation please